# pip install not working. How to resolve pip precedence issues?

Tags: python, pip

```
[qq88@qq88-pc ~]$ which -a pip
/home/qq88/.local/bin/pip
/usr/bin/pip
```

So it seems that after the python 3.8 update there is a conflict between which install takes precedence - right now it is `/home/qq88/.local/bin/pip` and not `/usr/bin/pip`. This causes issues when doing `pip install` like:

```
[qq88@qq88-pc ~]$ pip install ipython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/qq88/.local/bin/pip", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I went and installed it with `python -m pip install ipython` but:

```
[qq88@qq88-pc ~]$ ipython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/qq88/.local/bin/ipython", line 6, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython'
```

How do I run this now?
And more importantly, how do I make `/usr/bin/pip` take precedence or whatever else would resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it using the alias in your shell:

```
$ alias pip='/usr/bin/pip'
```

Then if you execute `$ alias pip` you should get :

```
alias pip='/usr/bin/pip'
```

Comment: that is indeed the case but this doesn't resolve '$ ipython' resulting in an error as shown above.